# name x is not defined when trying to refer to an object

Tags: python, class, pyqt5

The below code creates a simple window with a date-picker, and a button which activates the rest of the code (not the most elegant yet, and I'm using global variables here temporarily so the "processing" script can access them, these will be removed soon)

The problem is, when I create an object of the MyWindow class, I can't seem to access it at all in the functions called by `start_processing()`.

```
import calendar
import os
from datetime import date
from glob import glob
from time import time

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QComboBox, QPushButton, QLabel, QErrorMessage


def start_processing():
    start = time()
    files_found: tuple = file_search(month, year, r'O:\test\1 Originals')
    for i in files_found:
        process_file(i)
    duration = time() - start
    window1.set_text(f'Generation of files took {duration:.1f} seconds!')


class MyWindow(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = QApplication([])
        self.progress = QLabel('Foo')
        self.title = 'Bar'
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 300
        self.height = 300
        self.error_dialog = QErrorMessage()
        self.setup_ui()

    def setup_ui(self):
        self.app.setStyle('Fusion')
        window = QWidget()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        combobox_month = QComboBox()
        combobox_year = QComboBox()
        layout.addWidget(self.progress)
        layout.addWidget(combobox_month)
        layout.addWidget(combobox_year)
        combobox_month.addItems(calendar.month_name[1:13])
        combobox_year.addItems(['2017', '2018', '2019', '2020'])
        combobox_year.setToolTip('Select the year')
        combobox_month.setToolTip('Select the month')
        combobox_month.setCurrentText('January')
        combobox_year.setCurrentText('2019')
        process_button = QPushButton('Process')
        layout.addWidget(process_button)
        window.setLayout(layout)
        combobox_month.currentTextChanged.connect(self.on_combobox_month_changed)
        combobox_year.currentTextChanged.connect(self.on_combobox_year_changed)
        process_button.clicked.connect(self.on_button_clicked)
        window.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        window.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        window.show()
        self.app.exec_()

    @staticmethod
    def on_button_clicked():
        start_processing()

    @staticmethod
    def on_combobox_month_changed(text):
        global month
        month_lookup = {v: k for k, v in enumerate(calendar.month_name)}
        month = month_lookup[text]

    @staticmethod
    def on_combobox_year_changed(text):
        global year
        year = int(text)

    def set_text(self, text):
        self.progress.setText(text)
        self.app.processEvents()

    def error_message(self, text):
        self.error_dialog.showMessage(text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    window1 = MyWindow()
```

If I then try `window1.set_text('Blah')`, within the function `start_processing()` I get a `NameError: name 'window1' is not defined`.

start_processing is defined in the main body of the script, as are all functions except the ones included in this class.

Not sure how much of the entire script I need to post, but happy to add anything else.

Comment: Where is `start_processing` defined? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: In the main body of the script, will update Question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement `window1 = MyWindow()` will not actually assign a value to the variable `window1` until after `MyWindow()` has completely finished executing. Before `MyWindow()` can finish executing, `__init__()` must finish executing. But first `setup_ui` must finish executing. But first `exec_` must finish executing. But `exec_` blocks indefinitely as long as the window remains open. So when the user clicks on a button and triggers `on_button_clicked`, then `window1` will not yet have a value.

One possible solution is to move the `exec_` call so it is not called directly or indirectly by `__init__()`. For instance, you could call it at the file-level scope, right after creating `MyWindow()`.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    window1 = MyWindow()
    window1.app.exec_()
```

Comment: I'll get rid of the static method - I think this might have been a "fix" applied by PyCharm - thanks! All of the script is in the same .py file. Do I need to pass the window1 object as an argument to every function that calls on any of MyWindow()'s methods?

Comment: That's the idea. `window1` is not natively visible to functions defined in `start_processing`'s file, so you can expect all of them to fail to find `window1` unless you pass it as an argument.

Comment: Thank you. Although all functions are declared in the main body of the file. I would have thought if the functions are defined in the main body (not nested), and `window1` is also defined in the main body, that they'd be visible to each other? There's about 6 or 7 different functions that `file_search` calls (all are declared in the main body of the file). I presume I'd need to pass `window1` as an argument to every single function which invokes one of `MyWindow()`'s methods.

Comment: If `window1` and some functions are defined at the same scope, then you are correct that they would be visible to each other. But `window1` and `start_processing` are not in the same scope. `start_processing` is defined in one file, and `window1` is defined in another file. Each file gets its own scope.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by "file"? How are they in different files? Sorry if it wasn't clear, I did state a few times that the whole script is in the same file. Or do you not mean .py file, but something else? (Edited question to make clearer)

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood the problem. The issue is not scoping but rather the order of execution of statements in the call stack. I will revise my post.

Comment: Sorry, my fault for not being clearer! Makes perfect sense now. Thank you so much!

Comment: It was probably around comment #1 that I should have understood that you didn't have more than one file. I chalk this one up to a lapse in my own reading comprehension :-)